# Best practice with NUT in multi server, multi PSU, multi UPS setup?

Tags: power, ups

what is the common practice in powering and configuring multiple servers with multiple UPS when each server has two PSU?

Let's say I have 3 racks, each with it's own UPS and set of servers with two PSU. Simplest option is to power each PSU of each server from the UPS in the rack. Each server then have to monitor only a single UPS and proper shutdown procedure is easy to configure. With properly configured offdelay, ondelay and power on AC, server can be shut down during power outage and then turned on after power is restored.

But it feels wrong to power both PSU from same UPS. So another option is to power first PSU of each server from the UPS in the same rack and second PSU from UPS in another rack. It is easily configurable to shut down server when needed (if one, or both UPS are down and on low battery). But how to make sure, that server is then powered on? Server needs to lose power to both PSU for it to power on AC.

UPS have two controllable outlet groups, so this should be achievable, I wonder what is the best practice?

Comment: You connect each UPS to a different circuit (the same circuit) as the PSU is connected to.

Comment: Do ypu have 3 phase?  Multiple feeds from the grid? A genetator? Why do you eant to do anything other then monitoring and alerting?

Comment: Same circuit, no generator. Only 3 UPS and multiple servers.

And I need servers to power on after power is restored even if no one is at the location to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the best practice?

I have no idea.

> Server needs to lose power to both PSU for it to power on AC.

This is not really different from a single-PSU server. Even if it were connected to only a single PSU, a NUT-initiated shutdown followed by the grid power returning *before* the UPS finally died would still mean that the server would stay off, because it never lost AC power.

The server's *management controller,* however, would remain powered on the entire time. (I'm sure your servers have one.) So you could have a small "control host" configured with an 'On grid power' script whose job is to connect to each server's BMC in a loop (via IPMI or something fancier) and request the BMC to turn the server on.

This would change the problem to one of keeping just that single server always powered on, which could be achieved by *not* letting it shut down automatically at all – let it die with the UPS, and therefore return with the UPS as well. (Alternatively, the control server could be hosted elsewhere as long as it can reach the datacenter through a VPN.)

The same method *could* be used to toggle UPS outlets, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: So you recommend some scripting on independent host (this is current setup, that I would like to replace). I don't like the idea introducing another cog in the machine, that needs to be maintained and running. I even more don't like the idea of having scripts with passwords to IPMI in plaintext, so it can connect and power on the server.

Comment: Yes, it's not ideal and needs to be guarded closely, but the machine with NUT master running on it already has the ability to power off all servers. You can usually restrict IPMI access, e.g. there's an "operator" role with access to power but no write access to other IPMI parameters.

Comment: Problem is not with powering off, but powering on after power is restored.
Sure, I can limit user to allow only power on/off, but still, it is pretty big privileges to store passwords in plain text.

My question is primary whether there is some industry standards, or best practices to power on servers after power outage, if they have multiple PSU, each powered by different UPS.